# Ionic framework - Warning when emulating iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ios-simulator, ionic-framework

I keep getting this warning when executing "ionic emulate ios" on my app

```
2015-10-04 12:11:52.095 ios-sim[3757:81938] stderrPath: /Users/pablomartinez/MobileApps/MyApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2015-10-04 12:11:52.096 ios-sim[3757:81938] stdoutPath: /Users/pablomartinez/MobileApps/MyApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2015-10-04 12:11:52.220 ios-sim[3757:81938] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-8208/DVTFoundation/PlugInArchitecture/PlugInManager/DVTPlugInManager.m:257
Details: Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.DVTFoundation.DevicePlatformMapping
Object: 
Method: -extensionPointWithIdentifier:
Thread: {number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

I'm on Yosemite OSX 10.10.5
Xcode ver. 7.0.1
Ionic CLI ver. 1.6.5
Cordova ver. 5.3.3

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution from Ionic Forums 
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/warning-when-emulating-ios/33822/3

1. Uninstall cordova
2. Delete .cordova (hidden) directory from ~/
3. Delete platforms/ and plugins/ directories from my ionic project
4. npm install ios-sim -g
5. npm install ios-deploy -g
6. Make sure all the dependencies I have in package.json up to date
7. npm install
8. npm install cordova -g
9. ionic state reset
10. ionic emulate ios